# To remove the grids in an image using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to field of image processing in python opencv.

I want to remove the grid lines in the given image and show the output as a plain dark green image

I applied canny edge detection to detect the edges and then subtracting the image from edges . But its not showing the result as expected. Please suggest what can be done

[image: My input image]

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('Input image')

cv2.imshow("Original",image)
edges = cv2.Canny(image,100,200)

cv2.imshow("Canny",edges)
gray_image_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(edges, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
print gray_image_RGB.shape[:]
cv2.imshow("Converted",gray_image_RGB)

outputimage=image-gray_image_RGB
cv2.imshow("Output",outputimage)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Mmmm, how indicative is the image of the images you have to process? Is it actually the pattern or the colour you want to remove? I mean if someone produces some code that removes yellow pixels are you going to say *"Oh sometimes the grid is red, but it's always a grid"*. Can you clarify if the colours may be different? Or the pattern may be different? What I mean is, can I leverage the colour? Why not just make solid green image anyway? I feel you are not telling us the whole story here...

Comment: Hi Mark,
I want to remove the light green pattern in image. I specified grid because even if there is multiple color lines in the same image I should write a code that will able to remove that.
I hope I answered your question

Comment: It still doesn't make sense, sorry. This should do it. `cv::Mat mat(338, 338, CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(92,63,11));`

Comment: If the input image looks like this, but with different colour, just look find the most frequent colour and use something like what @MarkSetchell suggests. Otherwise I'd identify the grid (if you know color, then search for the color), and then use it as mask for inpainting.